# How to skip list data which already processed?

Tags: c#, loops, logic

For demo code, I have a `for` loop which calls a method `LoopData` based on some condition.

In `LoopData` method I am iterating a list `List<Data>` and this method again and again calling on various conditions and every time the whole list `List<Data>` is iterating.

Question is, how to skip those records from the list `List<Data>` which already processed in previous call?

Here's the code,

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data { Id = 1, ItemId = 100 },
            new Data { Id = 2, ItemId = 200 },
            new Data { Id = 3, ItemId = 300 },

            new Data { Id = 4, ItemId = 400 },
            new Data { Id = 5, ItemId = 500 }
        };

        for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                LoopData(data, 100, 300);
            }
            else
            {
                LoopData(data, 300, 500);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LoopData(List<Data> data, int startItemId, int endItemId)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            if(data[i].ItemId >= startItemId && data[i].ItemId <= endItemId)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to `Data` indicating that it is processed or not.

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
}
```

Set `Data.Processed` when you have processed the data!

```
private static void LoopData(List<Data> data, int startItemId, int endItemId)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!data[i].Processed &&
            data[i].ItemId >= startItemId && 
            data[i].ItemId <= endItemId)
        {
            //            
            data[i].Processed = True; // this data is processed
        }
    }
}
```